# How to enable cmake tool in ptxdist?

Tags: c++, embedded-linux

I am trying to compile csync package(http://ppa.launchpad.net/markhannon/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/c/csync/?C=M;O=D) for embedded system using ptxdist. To install this package it requires cmake tool but my ptxdist package is not enabled with cmake.

How can I enable/install cmake with ptxdist --- I already tried finding it in ptxdist menuconfig but there is no such option.

If it can not be done then how can I install this package.

I am using ptxdist-2012

Above question may be too silly as I am very new in this but tried all my options.

Comment: ask them directly, they have a mailing list : http://www.pengutronix.de/mailinglists/index_en.html and an irc chan : #ptxdist on freenode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no visible menu option for CMake. It's a host tool and you activate it by simply using a dependency on the host-cmake package. So for packages using CMake for build you have to do two things at least. In your `rules/mypackage.in` add

```
select HOST_CMAKE
```

In your `rules/mypackage.make` add

```
MYPACKAGE_CONF_TOOL     := cmake
```

For more advanced questions see other packages using CMake.